# LINQ Count() but don't return all rows

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I need to get a count of a DB table.
When I do the below I can see that the table enumerates (so looks like the rows come back then get counted on the app server side) but I'd like the SQL server to do the counting then return just the count.

```
db.Places.Where(x => x.City == 'San Jose').Count()
```

Comment: You can move your lambda body inside Count() and omit the Where call

Comment: No, it should get translated to SQL.  How can you "see that the table enumerates"?  If you're looking at the result of `Where` in the debugger then it _will_ execute on the server before counting.

Comment: Don't trust the debugger for Linq methods - hydrate the results to an array of list _then_ look at it in the debugger.  THere are too many squirrely things that happen in both EF and Linq-to-Objects that make the results look different in the debugger.

Comment: You can monitor your database server to see the SQL query that was executed. If you are using MS SQL Server, you can use SQL Profiler to see the SQL query that was sent to the database.

Comment: Yes I see it in the debugger. So are you saying that my query above that will just send something like select count(*)... to the SQL server and I won't have all the rows returned to the app server just the count I want?

Comment: Ahh yes thw SQL profiler shows it is just sending a count(1) query not a request for all the rows!

Comment: @mbird Correct - the query is generated when the `Count` bethos is called - if you try and "inspect" it before then you'll get misleading results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on the Linq to SQL provider that you're using, but most of them should translate your LINQ statement into an actual server side count.

You will need to enable logging on your provider or turn on profiling on your database in order to see what actual SQL was sent to it.

PS: Please tag with the appropriate provider and SQL server (for example: linq-to-sql sql-server)